# Creating a random file Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a ruby application right now that is storing data that is searchable. However, I wanted to create a file of the search results and was getting stuck. I found the `file.open("given_name.txt", "w")` command but I'm having trouble populating it with search results.

The results are determined in my class for `Mp3Meta` and returns from that as query in the active record base and populates it on screen in `index.html.erb`. I just am lost as to how to address this or make sure that the data is passed so I can properly create the file.

I wanted to parse it in this format but I'm not sure on the operators, I'm new to ruby and rails.

```
def save_result
    mp3 = Mp3Meta
    file.open("result.txt","w")
    file.put("#EXTM3U")
    for.each.mp3(file.put("#MP3INF"+ mp3.length + "," + mp3.artist_name + "-" + mp3.title + mp3.url))
    end
end
```

Comment: What is random about this file?

Comment: @jdl the physical location on the HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mp3 = Mp3Meta
```

This is literally assigning the *class* `Mp3Meta` to the variable `mp3`. You are probably trying to create an instance of the class, which would be `Mp3Meta.new`. If `Mp3Meta` is an ActiveRecord class (which you seem to mention obliquely in the question), then you really need to use a query on the class instead to get an enumerable of the results.

Other lines in the code exhibit similar confusions, particularly the `for.each.mp3` line, which is broken in at least 4 ways. :-)

I strongly recommend that you carefully go through a good Ruby tutorial, doing all the examples for yourself and trying minor modifications on your own. I recommend [Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/). Once you understand Ruby pretty well, *then* start learning Rails.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to create a random file on disk so that your file.open does not collide on multiple requests, then use tempfile to create the file.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/index.html